# non intrusuive Integration testing

Tags: java, integration-testing

I am writing integration tests for a messaging system.Most of the tests collect counts on the messgaes and their various code-paths end-to-end, at various stages of the flow. The tests I have currently have become far too intrusive in that I have many `public static AtomicInteger`s in these messaging components - I increment them on processing message - the tests then assert on these counts.

The worse part is that I will have to remove these counters when deploying to prod-  something that is prone to add bugs.

How do I design my tests such that I get the counts of the messages passing through these components without actually requiring to stuff-in counters all over my classes ? I was thinking of sub-classing the real components and overriding the methods , and moving the counters in the subclass methods - and using these subclasses in my tests - any other thoughts on better design ?

Comment: Is a full set of integration tests really the best solution? If you want to test the internals, do it in unit tests. Integration tests should only be used to test the externally exposed functionality.

Comment: Considering the number of use-cases , the number of unit tests needed to cover all combinations of code-paths become too high - almost causes a unit test fatigue . End to end testing is mandatory.

Comment: I wouldn't remove code that keeps track of statistics regarding system execution. You can expose this information using JMX and setup monitoring to keep an eye on the system in production. I would try to design it using the suggestions others already provided.

Comment: Latency and throughput considerations make it undersiable to have these counters ticking in live setup. But will give it a thought.

Comment: @SarelBotha, on second thoughts,  I think I can have a boolean configuration that decides if counting is needed or not. In tests , this would be true and in live env, this should be false. The only overhead this introduces from throughput point of view is a boolean check for every message.

Comment: Try to avoid premature optimization. 1. Build it the quickest and with the best design. 2. Test the performance and fix the bottlenecks if there are any. Often times the bottle neck isn't where you thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

Scattering your code with static `AtomicInteger`s used only in tests is certainly a bad idea. Here are few approaches I would recommend:

- use [jmx](/questions/tagged/jmx) or other monitoring mechanism available in your middleware to read the messages count in non-invasive way
- add possibility to install listeners in all your components. In production environments use `null` or null object pattern while in tests install some simple listeners to count invocations/messages. [di](/questions/tagged/di) will help you.
- use [aop](/questions/tagged/aop) or other instrumentation technology, similar to above.
- test side effects and output! Do not make assumptions on exact messages in the flow, just see whether the overall result is correct. This way your tests are much more flexible and focus on what is being tested. Unfortunately when something breaks debugging will take more time.

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with the exact similar scenario some time ago. I had several components processing some messages and then passing them to other components. I came up with this design:

- Every component implements an interface that has `notify` method used to notify and pass received messages to other components
- Every component holds a list of other components that need to be notified when a message is received
- In your tests, all what you have to do is to create a dummy processor that implements the interface defined above and register in all your components. This way the dummy processor gets notified whenever a new message flows in your system. While in production, there won't be dummy processors and that should make your code good for test and production releases.

Comment: Components that do not take any such interface would be forced to implement this interface - something that is equally intrusive, although I agree this is a cleaner approach than the one I am using currently.